# How are devices paired in CoreBluetooth?

Tags: ios, ios5, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Can someone explain to me how device pairing is done with Bluetooth 4.0 in the CoreBluetooth framework? With older Bluetooth models, pairing must be done in the iOS Bluetooth settings menu, but I have been reading from various online posts that this process can be completed from within the application. Is it automated when you connect to a device (which is in pairing mode) via `connectPeripheral`?

Thanks!

**Edit**

I should probably specify what I mean by 'pairing.' I am not referring to simply connecting, but to secure, saved connections made between the BLE peripheral and the iOS central application as referred to in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306347/android-ios-mobile-how-can-we-securely-do-bluetooth-pairing-without-promptin). I unfortunately do not have a programmed bluetooth low-energy device to test with, which would make things a lot easier to confirm.